# Problems sending parameters from Angular to Node

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm developing an easy website using Angular and nodeJS.
I'm trying to send one parameter "email" from an Angular service when accessing a route defined in node server.
The Angular service function:

[image]

The node defined accessing route:
[image]

The configuration of the node server:

[image]

I tried using bodyParser and using req.body for getting the email parameter sent from the frontend, but it seems to be lost.
It's getting an empty dictionary when req.params or req.body are printed.
[image]

Someone knows what can be happening?
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it you want to read the path-`param` from the request url (see route-params under https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

On the nodejs side, you need to change your handler to:

```
router.get('/profile/:email', ...) => {
   const email = req.params.email;
});
```

On the client-side, you need to correctly add the email path-segment. One way to do this is:

```
this.http.get<any>(`${this.URL}/profile/` + encodeURIComponent(email));
```

---

Instead of `path`-parameters you can also do this is using `query`-parameters. You'd need the following changes:

nodejs:

```
router.get('/profile', ...) => {
   const email = req.query.email;
});
```

angular:

```
this.http.get<any>(`${this.URL}/profile`, { params: { email } });
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! It's not any other way for sending it without been the parameter setted in the url? @eol

Comment: Not if you want it as a path-parameter. If you change it to query to can pass a query-object. I've updated my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, this helped to understand routing parameters. @eol